# Display job requests API ADO with includeCapabilities

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

does the ADO API allow me to get an answer that contains jobrequests but with &includeCapabilities=true&demands=key -equals value?

I tried https://dev.azure.com/org/project/_apis/distributedtask/pools/id/jobrequests?api-version=7.0&includeCapabilities=true&demands=key-equals value

and no project. Unfortunately, it didn't show what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

The demands for required agents are the properties defined on the pipeline rather than the agent pool (or agents).

Normally, the REST API for Requests is used to return when and which jobs have requested the agents in the pool. It would not return the demands defined on the pipeline.

To get the demands defined on the pipeline, you need to use the REST API for Pipelines "[**Pipelines - Get**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-7.0)". From the response of this API, you can get the demands defined on the agent jobs in the pipeline.

For example:

[image]